# How do you implement an auto-updating search box so that the names appear as you type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an index page where a table is generated with rows of information from the DB.

I have successfully integrated Tom Dykstra's method of adding a search box using this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

How would I implement behavior that shows names that already exist as they are being typed in the search box, or automatically update the rows in the table as something is typed into the search box?

I am using MVC 5 with EF6.

Thank you!

Comment: jqueryui is an option. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Answer (score 1):

I would use the jQuery UI Autocomplete widget with a remote source for the data.
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

For the remote source either write a new action on your controller that returns JSON, or a WebAPI action to do the same, and in there do a query against your database to find matching results for the users query

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use AngularJs. We can't give you a full example of this, I can only give you an approach. Angular is very powerful and as well it is client side which speeds up you application very much. See the example shown in the docs of angular.
You can use the filtering on everything (tables, divs, list etc.)

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Here is an example of how to implement AngularJS in Asp.Net MVC.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806029/Getting-started-with-AngularJS-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Par

Here is also an JSFiddle example on how it can look like:

http://jsfiddle.net/mikeeconroy/QL28C/1/

```
<tr ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search | orderBy:'name'">
        <td>{{product.name}}</td>
        <td>{{product.category}}</td>
    </tr>
```

This code snippet would do the filtering for you